# Ubuntu 16.04 takes too long to boot, shows errors and turns off suddenly

Tags: boot, 16.04, drm

When booting it shows a purple or black screen for a long time, something it didn't do before.
Then, some text appears, than I am not able to copy completely; I will tipe dots where I couldn't get it:

`drm:intel............................. (ERROR...)`

`clearing orphaned inode 12327092 (uid=1000) (gid=1000) (noe=...) (size=...)`

...

`/dev/sad1: clean, 481598/300007296 files, ......../300007296 blocks`

Then, when it boots, **it might suddenly turn off**. 
The unusual shut-down due to hardware problems might be the reason for the messages before? 
This might even make my computer to run slower in the long-time?

Results for systemd-analyze:

```
Startup finished in 23.558s (kernel) + 54.857s (userspace) = 1min 18.416s
```

Results for systemd-analyze critical-chain:

```
graphical.target @54.838s

└─multi-user.target @54.838s

  └─smbd.service @54.609s +227ms

    └─nmbd.service @49.579s +5.016s

      └─network-online.target @49.578s

        └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @26.921s +22.656s

          └─NetworkManager.service @24.670s +2.237s

            └─dbus.service @15.950s

              └─basic.target @15.883s

                └─sockets.target @15.883s

                  └─snapd.socket @15.878s +996us

                    └─sysinit.target @15.805s

                      └─apparmor.service @8.054s +7.660s

                        └─local-fs.target @7.866s

                          └─run-user-1000.mount @37.696s

                            └─local-fs-pre.target @7.866s

                              └─systemd-remount-fs.service @7.633s +106ms

                                └─systemd-journald.socket @3.015s

                                  └─-.slice @2.966s
```

Results for systemd-analyze blame:

```
systemd-analyze blame
     22.656s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
     16.250s click-system-hooks.service
     16.023s irqbalance.service
     15.922s grub-common.service
     15.673s networking.service
     15.577s apport.service
     15.470s gdomap.service
     15.408s speech-dispatcher.service
     12.319s ModemManager.service
     11.377s accounts-daemon.service
     10.628s dev-sda1.device
      9.921s user@1000.service
      9.082s systemd-logind.service
      8.902s console-kit-log-system-start.service
      8.896s alsa-restore.service
      8.894s gpu-manager.service
      8.894s systemd-user-sessions.service
      8.893s privoxy.service
      8.835s iio-sensor-proxy.service
      8.832s pppd-dns.service
      8.705s avahi-daemon.service
      8.704s thermald.service
      7.660s apparmor.service
```

Results for sudo fsck -f /

`481717/30007296 files (0,9 non-contiguous) 23729462/120028856 blocks`

So no references to orphane inodes.

It still takes some time to turn the screen different from black of purple anyway (there is not any ubuntu symbol as usual). And it turns off suddenly.

I updated Ubuntu recently to 16.04.
Thanks in advice for any help

Comment: So, question for you, does the black screen eventually go away and then the machine still boots, yes? I have a couple of ideas... did you install the `Intel Video Drivers for Linux`? Do you run with a wired network connection, or wireless. If wired, what happens if you boot with the ethernet cable disconnected? Do you know how to edit commands when viewing the GRUB menu?

Comment: Yes, the machine boots. I work with wireless conection. I am not familiar with the commands of the GRUB menu.
I have the hypotheses that this is a hardware problem. The computer turns off suddenly, it might be due to press the keyboard or the screen too hard. After this unusual shut-down, the computer shows `recovering journal` because it needs to clear orphane inodes.

Comment: Ah! The machine powers off? Is this a laptop, or desktop? How old? If laptop, do you run off battery or AC power? Do you have a vacuum cleaner with an exhaust port on it? Does the machine work more normally if you boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB?

Comment: The battery is completely empty since last year, so the machine needs to be plugged-in while working. It is a 4 years-old System-76. 
The Ubuntu Live DVD/USB works exactly equal.
The problem is getting worse: now, when I plug it, it might not even turn on the charging light for some time, in the meanwhile I can not turn it on.

Comment: You didn't say if you have a vacuum cleaner with an exhaust port. Are you saying that the Ubuntu Live DVD has the same symptom? Does the computer work any different if you remove the battery?

Comment: I am sorry I don't know it I have a vacuum cleaner with an exhaust port. The computer works equally with or without the battery. Maybe I should open and clean my computer in case this is the problem

Comment: short answer... it does sound like a hardware problem... many times it's that the machine is clogged with dust, and needs to be cleaned... and other times, the thermal paste that connects the processor heat sink to the top of the processor chip needs to be refreshed. If you have a vacuum cleaner that can blow, you can try (with the computer turned off and unplugged) blowing air into the vents of the computer to try and blow out any accumulated dust. Otherwise, you'll have to remove the bottom cover to do that, and to check the thermal paste. ps: do you have another AC adapter that you can try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DRM error` is related to your video subsystem. If there's just one error on occasion, then not to worry. It may actually be a minor bug in Ubuntu.

The `orphaned inode` indicates some disk corruption, and can be more serious. You'll want to run a fsck (file system check) asap.

The `/dev/sda1: clean` message is normally seen, even on 100% working systems. It is supposed to indicate that the file system is ok, but as we can see from the previous error, that's not the case.

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`